# Работа с range в PHP

Tags: php

Осваиваю синтаксис этого замечательного языка, и вот первый камень преткновения:

Есть такой массив:
`$quarters = array(1 => range(0, 15), 2 => range(16, 30), 3 => range(31, 45), 4 => range(46, 59));`

И есть функция, принимающая на вход число:

`function getQuarterOfAnHour($value){}`

Как мне можно проверить `$value` на то, что он входит в один из диапазонов `$quarters` и вернуть ключ этого диапазона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно циклом пройтись по `$quarters` и проверить через [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array) есть значение в массиве значений range или нет:

```
function getQuarterOfAnHour($value) {
    $quarters = array(1 => range(0, 15), 2 => range(16, 30), 3 => range(31, 45), 4 => range(46, 59));

    foreach ($quarters as $key => $range) {
        if (in_array($value, $range)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

var_dump(getQuarterOfAnHour(34)); // 3
```

Вот как-то так, только тут может быть `null` при условии, если значение больше 60, тоже стоит учитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
function getQuarterOfAnHour($someValue){
    global $quarters;
    foreach ($quarters as $k => $v){
        if(in_array($someValue, $v)) return $k;
    }
}
```

Comment: `global` лучше забыть как страшный сон

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, почему же?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-are-PHP-globals-bad

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, благодарю, обязательно прочту.